# How to trigger a pipeline in Azure Data Factory v2 or a Azure Databricks Notebook by a new file in Azure Data Lake Store gen1

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, databricks, azure-data-factory

I am using a **Azure Data Lake Store gen1** for storing JSON files. Based on these files i have Notebooks in **Azure Databricks** for processing them. Now i want to trigger such a **Azure Databricks** Notebook when a new file is creating in **Azure Data Lake Store gen1**. I couldnt find any Trigger which could do this. do you know any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is **not yet** implemented/Supported by *Microsoft*. But it is on their Roadmap(I believe).

You can do this in 2 ways,

1. Azure Functions(through Event Grid)
2. Logic Apps

---

### Option #1

Currently, Microsoft is building on #1.

You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/353).

As per this

> This feature is not a high priority for us right now, but I will note
>   that the announcement for Azure Event Grid listed Data Lake as one of
>   the integrations they are building. Once you can subscribe to Data
>   Lake updates through Event Grid, running an Azure Function would be
>   trivial (see here for some info).

You can [vote your voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/32983252-support-event-grid) to support the event grid (provider) in DataLake.

---

### Option #2

This is also not yet implemented, but you can [Upvote your voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/19528168-trigger-function-or-logic-app-when-file-is-added) here to support this feature